# Questions about animal health?

Tags: discussion

I'm surprised I can't find an answer to this. Are questions about animal health acceptable on this site, or only human health? The Tour page makes no mention either way, although the example question is about unicorns (but then, the example question doesn't seem to be related to health).

(The specific question I have in mind is in regards to cancer in a rat and how it is affected by prednisolone, which I think is related to human healthcare even though the question is not about a human.)

Comment: I've wondered this as well.  I don't know that Pets.SE is the best place or not.

Comment: So if nobody weighs in on this, can I just leave an answer and make a unilateral decision?